# Why is console.log showing properties of error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, prototype

```js
class AppError extends Error {
    constructor(cause, name, ...args) {
        const message = args.map(x => x.toString()).join(" ")
        super(message)
        this.name = name
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, AppError)
    }
}

throw new AppError(null, "name", "my", "message")
```

When I throw the error, the output looks like this:

```
throw new AppError(null, "name", "my", "message")
^

name: my message
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxx/test.js:21:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  name: 'name'
}
```

Why is it showing `{name: 'name'}`?

But when I throw a regular `Error` object it looks like this:

```
throw new Error("message")
^

Error: message
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxx/test.js:21:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

It doesn't show `{name: "name or something"}`

I am using `node ./test.js` to run this file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AppError` assigned a `name` property to the instance:

```
this.name = name
```

You aren't assigning anything to the plain old `Error` though. If you *do* assign such a property, you'll be able to see it:

```
const err = new Error('errormessage');
err.name = 'someerrorname';
throw err;
```

results in

```
someerrorname: errormessage
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Javascript\...\foo.js:1:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  name: 'someerrorname'
}
```

(Otherwise, what comes before the `:` will default to `Error`)

The same sort of thing is true for front-end:

```js
const err = new Error('errormessage');
err.name = 'someerrorname';
throw err;
```

> Uncaught someerrorname: errormessage

(without assigning to `err.name`, you get `Uncaught Error` instead)

If you want to remove the `{name: 'name'}`, make the property non-enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', { value: name, enumerable: false });
```

When logging an object, enumerable properties will be listed on it.

(You can also omit the `enumerable: false` if you want, since it defaults to `false` anyway)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to set `super.name = name` inside the constructor but I get the same result. How can I override the name from inside the constructor?

Comment: It seems to work when I do `Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {value: name})`. Is that how it is supposed to be used?

Comment: Oh, you want to *completely remove* the `name: 'name'` part? Yes, `Object.defineProperty` works, because it makes the property non-enumerable (and non-configurable).